# How does set insertion work in the following situation?

Tags: c++, stl, set

**The following structure :**

```
struct SomeStructure {
      uint64_t value;
      uint64_t data;
};

bool operator > (const SomeStructure& v1, const SomeStructure& v2) {
       return (v1.value > v2.value);
}
bool operator < (const SomeStructure& v1, const SomeStructure& v2) {
       return (v1.value < v2.value);
}
bool operator == (const SomeStructure& v1, const SomeStructure& v2) {
       return (v1.value == v2.value);
}
```

**Is used in a code similar to the following:**

```
SomeStructure st1, st2;
st1.value = st2.value = 10;  // has the same 'value'
st1.data = 20;    // but is assigned a different number for the 'data'. 
st2.data = 40;

std::set<SomeStructure> TheSet;
TheSet.insert(st1);
TheSet.insert(st2);
```

Will inserting `st2` after `st1` replace the value of the element present in the set?

In the above example, because the operators `>` and `<` are overloaded to only depend on the member `SomeStructure::value`, both `st2` and `st1` are considered to be equal while inserting them into `TheSet`. But the value of `SomeStructure::data` is different for both these objects. So will it replace the existing element in `TheSet` or will it ignore the insertion operation if the element is already present?

**Is there a way to explicitly enforce either of these two behaviors?**

**Will this behavior change with compiler and platform?**

**Edit 1:**

I just tested this out in g++ compiler (with c++11 enabled). It does not replace. So is there a way to explicitly enforce this to replace the existing element?

**Edit 2:**

Actually, there is no standard way to "enforce" this behavior, but it can be done using a simple *hack through*. Though This method is not recommended, let me present it here:

**This method must be used in place of the member function insert within std::set**

```
template <typename T>
void insert_replace(std::set <T>& theSet, const T& toInsert) {
      auto it = theSet.find(toInsert);
      if(it != theSet.end())
         *((T*)&(*it)) = toInsert;
      else
          theSet.insert(toInsert);
}
```

**And the above code must be replaced with:**

```
int main() {

    SomeStructure st1, st2;
    st1.value = st2.value = 10;  // has the same 'value'
    st1.data = 20;    // but is assigned a different number for the 'data'.
    st2.data = 40;


    std::set<SomeStructure> TheSet;

    insert_replace (TheSet, st1);
    insert_replace (TheSet, st2);


    for(auto ii : TheSet) {
        std::cout << ii.data;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

This method works fine on my compiler, giving the output : `40`, instead of `20`. But I think people might say this not a recommended method because, the line `*((T*)&(*it)) = toInsert;` fools the compiler into thinking that the iterator `it` isn't a constant (but when it actually is). I believe this is the only way we can force `std::set` to insert by replacing. Is it fine to use this method in my code? or will it cause problems in the future (even if I document it)?

Comment: Have you read the friendly manual?

Comment: If you want it to insert both of them, change your comparison functions so that they check both `value` and `data`. Otherwise it's ignored.

Comment: Actually, it is supposed to only depend on `value`. My code requires it to replace the existing element with the new one. But is the behavior part of the standard? Or will it change with compiler?

Comment: `set` will use only `operator<`for comparisons. You don't need the others (for this example)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/):

> the insertion operation checks whether each inserted element is equivalent to an element already in the container, and if so, the element is not inserted

So `TheSet.insert(st2);` will not insert anything, because `st2` is equal to `st1`, which is already in the set.

If you want to be able to insert both of them, you need to change the comparison functions so they test both `value` and `data`, or use `std::multiset`, which allows duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I deliberately made it depend on only `value`. I also want it to replace `st1`, when `st2` is inserted. Now I think the opt data structure for this kind task is `std::map` and not `std::set`.